# $f(a+b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$

Tags: functional-equations

So I'm working on a question:

$f(a+b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$

$f(1) \cdot f(2) = 8$

What is $f(1) \cdot f(3)$?

-

I've figured out that $f(3) = 8$ but I can't seem to play with the fuctions so that I get $f(4)$, which should be $f(1) \cdot f (3)$.

I'm sure it's some really simple arithmetic thing I'm missing.

Comment: Hint: $f(2) = f(1+1) = ?$

Comment: $f(x)$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: is $f(x)$ is a real function, it must be if the form $f(x)=k^x$

Comment: @WW1 Which is false. The formula only holds for rational $x$.

Comment: You do have an exponential function $a^x$ and the value of $a$ is almost done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then

$$f(n)=f(1+\cdots+1)=f(1)\cdots f(1)=f(1)^n$$

and thus by your assumption

$$8=f(1)f(2)=f(1)f(1)^2=f(1)^3$$

and therefore $f(1)=2$ (assuming we are working over $\mathbb{R}$) and now we can apply the original formula again to obtain:

$$f(2)=4$$
$$f(3)=8$$
$$f(4)=16$$
$$\cdots$$
$$f(n)=2^n$$

Note that this can be extended to all rationals, i.e. if $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $f(q)=f(1)^q$. However this is no longer true for all reals (unless additional conditions are assumed, e.g. continuity of $f$).

Comment: That's it :D I knew it was something simple like that. Thank you